# html2pdf works on localhost but not on a remote server

Tags: php, symfony, html2pdf

I'm using [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) library to generate PDF file, the weird thing is that my function works fine locally but when I upload it on a remote server it does not work anymore !
I'm using this library with my symfony project, I did not use a bundle I just downloaded the library via composer then used it directly in the controller:

```
public function pdfAction(){

        $view = $this->renderView('@BusinessPieces/piece/pdf.html.twig');

        $html2pdf = new \HTML2PDF();
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($view);


        return new Response($html2pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I'), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
    }
```

This is my view pdf.html.twig:

```
<page orientation="portrait" format="A4" style="font-size: 18px">
    <h1>Exemple d'utilisation</h1>
    <br>
    Ceci est un <b>exemple d'utilisation</b>
    de <a href='http://html2pdf.fr/'>HTML2PDF</a>.<br>
</page>
```

This is what I get on localhost:
[image]
And this is what I get on a remote server:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How did you install it on the server? What does your error-log say? Composer pulls needed dependencies, as far as I know, maybe you're missing something on the server.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I just uploaded my project to the server and tried to use it, and I have nothing in the error-log file because there is no exception. When I want to generate a pdf file I get a blank page.

Comment: Which means there should be an error somewhere - turn on all errors in PHP, perhaps, or check other logs. I would assume it has to do with missing dependencies somewhere, probably a library the html2pdf needs to work.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie other logs like what ?

Comment: Possibly the apache logs at /var/log/apache2 ? Your apache error log and also vhost site logs should be within.

Comment: I found this exception:[2017-03-31 14:49:57] php.DEBUG: Warning: unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 0 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/home/milanodmcc/public_html/demo/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php\",\"line\":1930})"} []